# Pass jsp variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am curious as to how I should be passing a variable from my .jsp page to my JavaScript file. Currently I have the following...

```
<c:forEach items="${stats}" var="s" >
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var status = "hello";
        </script>
            <div class='memory' id='memory'>
                <p id='text'>Memory<p>
            </div>
            <div class='memory1' id='memory1'>
                <p id='text'> Memory 2</p>
            </div>  
             <script  src="js/temp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </c:forEach>
```

This works just fine for `alert(status);` However I am wondering how I should go about passing the field of `{$s.status}` to the javascript file as changing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var status = {$s.status};
</script>
```

does not work

Comment: You mean dynamically change with the server value? ,,, then that is not possible unless it either gets pushed to the client/browser, or the client asks for it, using e.g. an Ajax call.

Comment: the idea is yes the value will be changing as per a defined refresh rate. I am retrieving statistics about another running application such as memory used and status, and need to draw a progress bar on the screen. I am wondering then what the best way would be to go about this as it sounds like the way I originally wanted is a bit convoluted...

Comment: Ok, so what I suggested is a couple ways, and yet another is websockets, but again, which is based on how/what your are going to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
<input type="hidden" value="${s.status}" id="status">
<script>
   var status = document.getElementById('status').value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use something like:

`var status = '${s.status}';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = <%=request.getParameter("test")%>;
```